# Convert a Smart Form into PDF in an Xstring variable

Tags: pdf, abap, sap-smart-forms

I have to generate a Smart Form in PDF format. I have to save this output (in any possible format which I would say is type either `string` or `xstring`) in a Z table so it can be generated again without the processing.

Could you please clarify if there is any way of saving the Smart Form PDF in `xstring` type?

I have looked into the output of function module that generates the Smart Form and tried to look for `xstring` but was unable to find it.

Comment: It seems that your question is to "archive" the PDF result of a Smart Form generation so that to be able to regenerate it identically, but you are limiting the question to "converting a PDF into string/xstring". Can you confirm your question please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `CONTROL_PARAMETERS` importing parameter of the function module you use to output the Smart Form, pass the field `GETOTF = 'X'` in order to receive the field `OTF_DATA` from the exporting parameter `JOB_OUTPUT_INFO`.

Then you can convert the field OTF_DATA into PDF format with the function module `CONVERT_OTF`.

That gives you a binary table that you can convert to the `xstring` type using the function module `SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be the way to do it  :) 
It worked as intended